# adding icons to sir trevor blocks

Tags: javascript, rich-text-editor, sirtrevor

I am trying to add a new [Sir Trevor](http://madebymany.github.io/sir-trevor-js/docs.html) block that I created for a web application we are making. However, I just can't figure out how to add icons for Sir Trevor to use. There is a folder called images/icons/src but that seems to be ignored. So, where DO they go?

-Ferdy

Comment: http://madebymany.github.io/sir-trevor-js/docs.html#3-2 ?

Comment: No, that's a short description of how the Image block works. I meant the icons that are shown when you pick what kind of block you want to add.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in my application and the solution that I found is this website: http://icomoon.io/app/#/select

There are some icons for free and you can upload SVG files to create custom fonts(icons). 
Basicaly, you should select some icons and advance to the configuration page, where you should input a ligature (this is the icon_name in your block) and, in “preferences”, you should select “Encode & Embed Font in CSS”, and then download it. You will have a zip file, and in the style.css you will get the base64 encoded of the font (.woff) file ....this string should be placed in sir-trevor-icons.css.

This solution works fine for me.Good luck! 
Regards,
Mauricio Baum Jr.